# read_csv date parsing fails when date column is not an index

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

**read_csv** does not seem to work when column is not an index. Why?

This does not work:

```
from pandas import read_csv
from StringIO import StringIO


data = """Data,Sample\n9-Oct-14,Sample 1\n,Sample 2\n"""

read_csv(StringIO(data), parse_dates=True)



Out[19]:
    Data        Sample
0   9-Oct-14    Sample 1
1   NaN         Sample 2
```

This works:

```
read_csv(StringIO(data), parse_dates=True, index_col=0)


Out[20]:
            Sample
Data    
2014-10-09  Sample 1
NaT         Sample 2
```

Comment: 'What' is not working? Can you show the output and note what is not correct?

Comment: See the docstring of `read_csv`, explanation of `parse_dates`: "If True -> try parsing the index." So this works when you specify which column should be the index. Another option is specify which column to parse with `parse_dates`

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

```
read_csv(StringIO(data),parse_dates=['Data'])

Out[27]:
    Data        Sample
0   2014-10-09  Sample 1
1   NaT         Sample 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Python 3.4.1 on Mac OS X and a slightly adapted code I get exactly the same output with both of the provided data streams or code snippets.

CODE:

```
from pandas import read_csv
import io


data1 = """Data,Sample\n09-Oct-14,Sample 1\n,Sample 2\n"""
data2 = """Data\tSample\n01-AUG-09\tSample 1\n\tSample 2\n"""

df1 = read_csv(io.StringIO(data1),parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
df2 = read_csv(io.StringIO(data2),sep='\t',parse_dates=True, index_col=0)

print(df1)
print('\n')
print(df2)
```

OUTPUT:

```
              Sample
Data                
2014-10-09  Sample 1
NaT         Sample 2


              Sample
Data                
2009-08-01  Sample 1
NaT         Sample 2
```